# Add datepicker in prestashop registration form (birthdate)

Tags: jquery, datepicker, prestashop

In the previous version of Prestashop 1.6 the registration form has datepicker for birthday field with a dropdown list where we can select month, day, year.

Prestashop Version 1.6 - Birthdate screenshot:
[image: Prestashop Version 1.6 - Birthdate screenshot]

Then in the latest version of Prestashop 1.7.6+, the registration form for the birthdate field doesn't have datepicker, we need to manually type in date in the birthdate input field.

Prestashop Version 1.7.6+ - Birthdate screenshot:
[image: Prestashop Version 1.7.6+ - Birthdate screenshot]

Where should I modify the file in order to show the date picker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prestashop already has helper form of birthday field:

Find the file ../classes/form/CustomerFormatter.php

in line 196 change the `setType('text')` to `setType('date')`:

```
if ($this->ask_for_birthdate) {
    $format['birthday'] = (new FormField())
        ->setName('birthday')
        ->setType('date')   //change this to date
        ->setLabel(
            $this->translator->trans(
                'Birthdate',
                [],
                'Shop.Forms.Labels'
            )
        )
```

Comment: I'm using the format "DD-MM-YYYY" in my system, but when I changed the birthdate field to `setType('date')`, the selected value in the datepicker becomes "MM-DD-YYYY". Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the browser's system language, instead of the system locale setting. Using my cellphone the selected value was inputted as "DD-MM-YYYY". Is there any way to change this?